# Animation on one object's duplicate?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have a simple issue that I'm trying to get around fixing. On trigger, an object is added and a message gets sent to that object. When the message is sent, the object plays an animation. The problem is that the animation gets played to all the objects and not the new one. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: If you use direct hooking instead of messaging, when you duplicate the objects out, everything should still work on an individual basis. I know it's sloppy, but it works.

Comment: What is the issue? All objects play the animation except the added one? or all object play the animation? or do you want a specific object to play the animation only?

Comment: Simple- the message is sent and *then* the object is added. your new object **never gets the message**

Comment: Even though you have the object getting added and the message getting sent in the same logic tick, essentially, your new object never gets the message.

Comment: Newly added objects get the messages from the last frame (when the edit object actuator was activated). It would not work if you use the message to add the new object and to trigger the animation. Then it is better to use two messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by simply putting an always > and > action, this will play separately on all objects.